# C# get google plus page using placeid

Tags: c#, google-plus, google-places-api

I am using Google Places API Web Service. Place search and Place details to get business information. Is it possible using **placeid** or some other way to get business google plus page? and get details such as Tagline? Description?

example or link would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is very much so possible. This can all be done using the Google Places API with Web Service calls. Documentation for the API can be found here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro

The http request call will look something like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?parameters
```

With you filling in the appropriate desired output parameters. Check out the Place Details page as well for more specifics on what you are trying to do.

**EDIT:** I misread the original and included the link for the Places API, rather than the Google+ API. The documentation for this can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/

The appropriate call you are looking for will then be this GET request: `GET  /people/userId`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am using place details [link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) and if looking at the example it is returning url attribute [link](http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=10281119596374313554) but this is not google+ page and I am looking for this e.g. page [link](https://plus.google.com/+Flowersinsyrup) and if clicking on the about button it shows tagline & introduction/description (i want that information too if possible). I hope it makes sense what I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: userid would be the placeid (used from place details?) of the business I am trying to get information from?